# SocketIO cannot access JSON properties from ON

Tags: json, node.js, socket.io, ecmascript-6

I don't know if I'm going crazy here but I'm doing something very basic that would usually be trivial, but I've been stuck on it for awhile now.

I'm receiving a message from a client like so:

```
            socket.on('request_username', function(messageFromClient) {

            if(messageFromClient == undefined) {
                Logger.logError("messageFromClient was undefined in socket_api.js");
                return;
            }

            // Parse the message into Json, might not be needed.
            // Logs: "{\"username\":\"test\"}"
            console.log(messageFromClient);

            try {
                messageFromClient = JSON.parse(messageFromClient);
                //Logs: {"username":"test"}
                console.log(messageFromClient);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log("Error parsing json from request_username. Mesage is %s", err);
                return;
            }

        // All undefined.
        console.log(messageFromClient['"username"']);
        console.log(messageFromClient["username"]);
        console.log(messageFromClient['username']);

            // msg == undefined incase the parse failed.
            if(messageFromClient == undefined || messageFromClient.username == undefined) {
                Logger.logError("messageFromClient.username was undefined in socket_api.js");
                return;
            }

            var usernameRequested = messageFromClient.username;
```

Now I'm getting this in the logs

```
"{\"username\":\"test\"}"
{"username":"test"}
Log Error: messageFromClient.username was undefined in socket_api.js
```

I've no idea what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: If you're using ES6, you should use lambdas. I suspect those escaping slashes are your issue. You're looking for `messageFromClient.username` when you are getting `messageFromClient['"username"']` as a key

Comment: I tried passing ```{username:"test"}``` as well and it broke. I still get the same error

Comment: So you tried `messageFromClient = { username : "test" };` and it was still undefined?

Comment: That works, so something wrong with the parsing?

Comment: Where is the sending code so we can see exactly how/what you're sending the message?  socket.io automatically serializes to/from JSON so you don't need to do that yourself.  In fact, if you do, it can mess things up.

Comment: I'm sending it from a tool called 'Socket IO Tester' chrome extension

Comment: That doesn't help us know what exactly is being sent.

Comment: Well when I log the data being sent it seems like json but I can't access it's properties

Answer (score 1):

With socket.io, it automatically serializes Javascript data to/from JSON.  You do not have to do that and if you attempt to, you can mess things up.

In socket.io, you can send like this:

```
var data = {username: "test"};
socket.emit('request_username', data);
```

Then, on the receiving side, you would have:

```
socket.on('request_username', function(data) {
    console.log(data.username);   // will show "test"
});
```

The serializing to/from JSON is done automatically by the socket.io library (one of its many useful features).

---

To debug your particular situation further, we will need to know exactly what the very first `console.log(messageFromClient)` shows right when the message first arrives before you've done anything to it?

You show a bunch of log info, but it's not entirely clear which debug line corresponds with which line of code.  If that very first console.log shows:

```
"{\"username\":\"test\"}"
```

then your message is apparently still JSON which is probably because it was doubly JSON encoded which is an error on the sending side.  This should be fixed on the sending side rather than trying to double parse it.

---

Also, when discussing this problem please be aware that JSON is a string format.  A Javascript object is something you can directly access properties on in Javascript code.  It appears you are sometimes calling them both JSON which is confusing for all.  You convert a Javascript object to JSON with `var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj)` and you convert JSON to a Javascript object with `var obj = JSON.parse(someJSON)`.

```
var obj = {username: test};           // Javascript object
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);    // produces a JSON string
var obj2 = JSON.parse(jsonStr);       // parses JSON string back to a Javascript object
```

Comment: I get ```undefined``` for ```console.log(messageFromClient.username);``` the json I'm sending is ```{"username":"test"}```

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns - I added more to the end of my answer.

Comment: I'm still getting this darn error, maybe the Socket.io tester is sending weird chars? Do you know any other way I can test sockets easy?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns - As I said, I have no idea what the socket.io tester is sending.  Perhaps it is just configured to send strings, not objects.

Comment: But if it's configured to sent strings then why is the JSON.parse failing?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns - What exact string are you typing into the tool and what does the very first `console.log(messageFromClient)` show before you've done anything to `messageFromClient`?  `JSON.parse()` would fail if you weren't given it legal JSON.  My guess is you're' typing a typical Javascript object literal into the tool and the tool is sending it as a plain string, but that is not legal JSON.

Comment: ```{"username":"test"}``` I can confirm that ```JSON.parse``` is producing a string ```typeof messageFromClient``` after parse is 'string'

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns - It appears the tool is forcing everything to be a plain string by taking whatever you type in and adding quotes around it.  `JSON.parse()` will then treat that as nothing more than a string.  The problem is your tool.  There's probably a way to trick the tool into sending something you can recognize, but is that really worth the effort?  The tool will not easily send the desired JSON.  It's not a useful tool for testing this.  If I could try a bunch of things out myself, I could probably figure out how to trick it, but not with this sort of remote conversation.

Comment: The weirdest thing is this:
```var messageObject = JSON.parse(messageFromClient);
   console.log(typeof messageObject);
   console.log(typeof JSON.parse(messageFromClient));```
The first console log returns string, the second one returns object...

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns - That makes it look like it is triply JSON encoded, first by you, then the tool turns that into a JSON string and then socket.io JSON encodes that.  socket.io undoes the first JSON encoding, but then when you first get the message it's still doubly encoded.  The tool is clearly not meant for sending objects, only strings.

Comment: But what I don't get is that it's a plain string. Why would that fail?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns - Sorry, but I'm bowing out of trying to explain a tool I've never seen and can't debug myself and clearly isn't the right tool for what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can ignore the tool, the message is actually a plain string. :-/

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns - Like my answer shows, if you send with socket.io from Javascript, you get the same type on the receiving end that you originally sent.  If you send a string, you receive a string.  If you send a Javascript object, you receive a Javascript object. So, any situation where you're not getting that through the tool is because of shenanigans that the tool is doing.  I don't want to try to figure out what the tool is doing any more.